# Use an async function from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, typeerror, solidity

I'm working on coding a Dapp with the react boxe from truffle. For that application I need to use a function (just two getters) from my smart contract in another component than `App.js`. This function is the `getUser`, which needs to be in form from `Login.js`.

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    web3: null,
    contract: undefined,
    account: null,
    user: {
      id: null,
      name: '',
      password: ''
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const web3 = await getWeb3();
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = Login.networks[networkId];
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        Login.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );
      this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract.       
         Check console for details.`,
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  getUser = async (event) => {
    const userID = this.state.id;
    const userName = await this.state.contract.methods 
                     .getUsername(userID).call();
    const userPassword = await this.state.contract.methods 
                        .getPassword(userID).call();
    console.log(userName + ' - ' +userPassword);
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.web3) {
      return <div>Loading Web3, accounts, and contract...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Login.js:

```
class App extends Component{

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    let input = event.target;
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = input.value;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }
render() {
    return (
      <div className='Login'>
        <form>
          <label>
            <span>Barcode:</span>
            <input name="id" type="number" required    
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit" value="submit">Get user data</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

> I first tried to export the `getUser` function:
>
> App.js:
>
> ```
> export const getUser = async (event) => {
>         const userID = this.state.id;
>         const userName = await this.state.contract.methods 
>                          .getUsername(userID).call();
>         const userPassword = await this.state.contract.methods 
>                             .getPassword(userID).call();
>         console.log(userName + ' - ' +userPassword);
>       };
> ```
>
> Login.js:
>
> ```
> import {getUser} from ...
> ```
>
> But I got the following error:
>
> ```
> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
> ```

> I then tried to add inside the `Login`, the same `componentDidMount`
> and `state` found inside `App.js` (with the imports), however I got
> the following error:
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'methods' of null
> ```

I no longer have any idea of how to do it. So I would like to ask some help please.

I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to help me.

Comment: So `getUser` refers to `this.state` which won't really work outside the component class, why not instead update the function to just take an `id` and `contract` so that it can be more easily exported?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I understand what you mean by saying to update the function to just take an `id`, but I don't understand how to do it with `contract` :/...

Comment: Taking a step back, it sounds like less about having a shared function, which could work simply by passing the values it needs to it, and instead sharing state such as `contract` across different components?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I'm really sorry but I still don't understand. Could you show me an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the value between components. Let's say onClick you will move from login to app component and you will pass id & name.

```
onClick=(id,name)=>{
  history.push({
           pathname: '/secondpage', //app component url
           state: { id: id, name: name }
       })
}
```

history could be imported from react-router

Then in app component you can access this value in, `this.props.location.state`

If you want to send value through component, in login component declare app component like this,

```
<App 
  id={id}
  name={name}
/>
```

Then in app component you can get the value in `this.props`

Answer (score 0):

## Global State Management

You are looking for a way to manage state at a global level. There are lots of solutions for this problem that exists and are widely used.

### Solution 1: Props or "prop drilling"

The idea is to pass the state to every component that needs it. You should only consider doing this if you are passing down props that are not global level or is needed by only a few component trees.

> An example of passing down props is in the official docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

### Solution 2: React Context API

There is already a built in feature inside React that is widely used called Context API that solves this. Example of usage is also in the docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to
> pass props down manually at every level.

**TLDR;** If you need to your state to be at a global level where lots of component trees need access to it, this is probably the solution.